# How to clone a Debian package for a daemon?

Tags: debian, nginx

I have to maintain several builds of nginx (with different sets of modules compiled in).  These will be cloned from official package, with Replaces:/Conflicts: added, and will have different names (nginx-foo, nginx-bar...) but the same version number.  I'd like to leave file names the same (/usr/sbin/nginx etc.); however, if I simply change the package name in debian/control, the binary name changes to .../nginx-foo too.

If anyone did that already, please share your solution.

Comment: Leave them be and add a postinst script that does `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/nginx nginx /usr/bin/nginx-foo 50` or similar?  If nothing else conflicts then you can even have multiple binaries installed and simply use `update-alternatives --set` to switch between them.

Comment: I don't think update-alternatives will work with the default scripts provided by the nginx package. /etc/init.d/nginx calls /usr/sbin/nginx directly for example. It doesn't just call "nginx".

Comment: Hm, I could use dpkg-divert ...